# how to pass the dynamic data from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to load the image dynamically from the database, for that i used like:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("GetImage/${ID}", "Home")' alt = "${name} image" />
```

But it not reflecting to the controller,but if i put statically like:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("GetImage/1", "Home")' alt = "${name} image" />
```

Then it is reflecting to the controller and it is displaying image.
I want to send the ID dynamically from view to the controller.
How to concatenate the dynamic value with the "GetImage"

My controller code is:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
{
  var imgquery = (from img in dbContext.Listdetails where img.ID == id
  select new
  {
    Image = img.Image
  }).FirstOrDefault();
  {
    System.IO.MemoryStream outStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    byte[] Image = imgquery.Image;
    return File(Image, "Image/jpg");
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is that ${ID} and ${name}? seems to me like not a razor syntax? To access the server side variables you have to use @.

Comment: this is the dynamic content.${name},${ID} gives dynamic data in the database.I am able to get the values individually if i put it in alert,but when i gave like  "GetImage/${ID}",these are not effecting the controller.

Comment: If that is a dynamic content where and how you are replacing it?